# 1X1 filter with stride 2 deep learning specialization on coursera

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am taking deep learning specialization on coursera. In the second week assignment of the course 4 (ResNets), there is below code

in `# First component of main path` Conv2D function has parameters `F1, (1, 1), strides = (s,s)`. Does that mean it is a 1X1 filter with stride of 2? that doesnt make sense because we would be missing an alternate pixel. Is my understanding correct?

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: convolutional_block

def convolutional_block(X, f, filters, stage, block, s = 2):
    """
    Implementation of the convolutional block as defined in Figure 4

    Arguments:
    X -- input tensor of shape (m, n_H_prev, n_W_prev, n_C_prev)
    f -- integer, specifying the shape of the middle CONV's window for the main path
    filters -- python list of integers, defining the number of filters in the CONV layers of the main path
    stage -- integer, used to name the layers, depending on their position in the network
    block -- string/character, used to name the layers, depending on their position in the network
    s -- Integer, specifying the stride to be used

    Returns:
    X -- output of the convolutional block, tensor of shape (n_H, n_W, n_C)
    """

    # defining name basis
    conv_name_base = 'res' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'
    bn_name_base = 'bn' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'

    # Retrieve Filters
    F1, F2, F3 = filters

    # Save the input value
    X_shortcut = X


    ##### MAIN PATH #####
    # First component of main path 
    X = Conv2D(F1, (1, 1), strides = (s,s), name = conv_name_base + '2a', kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + '2a')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
```